# "Company Name Presents..." - what does it mean?

Tags: credits

In the beginning of a movie, multiple companies associated with the production show off their fancy (and sometimes not so fancy) logo intro clips.

I've noticed sometimes one of the companies will also have "Our Name Presents.." and I'm curious what the meaning is.

Comment: It's probably case-by-case.  The roots of this likely go back to _radio_ productions, when manufacturers ran their [own shows or broadcast companies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap_opera).  Or maybe earlier - check playbills from the 1700s/1800s.  Essentially, it was another form of advertising.  With modern production companies, though, it's different - "we make stuff you like to watch", not "you like this, so buy our stuff".

Comment: *Is the presentation of the film given to the highest bidder, the company with the movie rights, or what?*... could you try and make a little more sense out of this?

Comment: Typically a "presenter" is the executive producer. However, it can also be a production company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually means that they either paid to have some sort of credit for the production, or an odd form of advertising without anyone realizing it, thus getting people to watch more movies produced by them.